# Is this transitive or intransitive?

Tags: transitivity

Let's consider this situation. A mother asks her child, "Who ate this apple?"
Then her son replies, "I didn't eat." In this situation, is "eat" an intransitive verb when "the apple" is omitted? I think "eat" is transitive verb originally. What do you think?

Comment: I assume a mom is female and would address *her* child.

Comment: I don’t understand the question.  If you are eating an apple, then that apple is the direct object.  If you are simply eating, then there is of course no direct object.  Is your question about something more than that?

Comment: I think it's General Reference that *to eat* can be transitive or intransitive. Grammatically, it's irrelevant that in OP's *intransitive* usage, the strong implication is the son didn't eat *the apple* (since he didn't eat *[**anything**]*).

Comment: **But** this brings up the extremely common illusion -- to which we often contribute -- that a verb is intrinsically transitive or intransitive. This is why I talk about transitivity being a property of clauses, not verbs. If you want to say there's a missing but understood indefinite edible direct object of _eat_ in this sentence, then you'll want to say it's Transitive. If you don't want to insert missing words and pretend they're there, then you'll want to say it's Intransitive. Same with Passive; same with Dative; same with any rule that changes object configuration.

Comment: Executive Summary: [Transitivity](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/logicguide.pdf) is **not** General Reference.

Comment: @JohnLawler I intentionally propagating the myth in my comment, and just noted two different clauses.

Comment: It's one type of theory, and it works well for some stuff and not so well for others. Like most theories. Which is why there are so many of them. It's this presupposition that `Everything Must Be Labelled Correctly And There Is Only One Correct Label` that causes all the trouble. There is just way too much misinformation about English floating around to use terms like _transitive_ confidently. Everybody has their own idea about what it means, and they cling to it. Most of the questions at ELU ask for binary choices; where does that idea come from?

Comment: "Who ate this apple?" takes a bit of thinking about. One might assume that the referent, never mind the direct object, would have to be assumed. Leaving that aside, _eat_, like many verbs normally used with a direct object, may be used without one: I haven't eaten yet. / Do you drink? / We have a tennis court. Do you play? There is often an obvious candidate for direct object. However, in the OP's example, "I didn't eat" is distinctly non-standard in response to the question.

Comment: @JohnLawler [Do you have any apples in that basket?](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-JPfVGotIQI)

Comment: @JohnLawler: _Most of the questions at ELU ask for binary choices; where does that idea come from?_ -And when one attempts to answer what one feels is the question-behind-the-question, one is accused of 'not answering my question'. The good old "Have you stopped being stupid yet?" ploy.

Comment: @JohnLawler I’ll bet that consigning all choices to binary, and indeed boolean, selections is driven by ESL tests whose facile questions can be marked only right or wrong by some mindless algorithm, not carefully graded for excellence or completeness, let alone for actual understanding, by a human agent. Everything is only ever right or wrong, and no allowance is made for multiply correct, shaded responses.

Comment: @tchrist It wouldn't be so bad if one of the offered answers was correct - or even both of them - or even if the question allowed sensible discussion in an approach to an answer - or even if the question made sense - all the time.

Comment: This is not just for ESL; native English speakers are not educated about their language in Anglophone classrooms, either, with the results that we see daily. They may **think** they are, but there's the same anxious cluelessness everwhere.

Comment: Sure, but native speakers aren’t often confronted with questions like “Is *burn* a transitive verb or an intransitive one?”. It seems very specialist to me — not to mention a horrible question. And one would hope that if they really were doing specialist work, they’d be given better questions than that sort.

Answer (score 1):

I will try to avoid begging the transitive question.

When *eat* is used without a direct object it usually has a somewhat different meaning than it does when used with a direct object: something closer to ‘take a meal’. For instance:

- You're in plenty of time, we haven't eaten yet = *Dinner has not yet been served*.
- No, thanks, I ate already = *I already had lunch*.

In some circumstances, to be sure, it does imply *eat something*:

> I'm famished, I haven't eaten at all today = *I haven't eaten anything today.*

But U.S. children would not answer the question *Who ate this apple?*<sup>†</sup> with *I didn't eat*—that would be non-responsive, because it answers a different question. They would be more likely to say something like *I didn’t eat it!*<sup>‡</sup>

---

<sup>†</sup>Actually, this question would probably not be asked, since the apple is no longer present. The question would probably be *Who ate **that** apple?*

<sup>‡</sup>Actually, they would probably answer *Not me!*—which would come out *Dobbe!*, because their mouth would be full.

Comment: ...... Beat yer.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth So you did. I'm a  s l o w  writer.